# Use delegates to Convert wcf service return object

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, delegates

The function below takes any wcf service method and invokes it.

```
Private Function ServiceCall(ByVal functionToCall As ServiceDelegate(Of IEmpService)) As Object
    Dim channel As New ChannelFactory(Of IEmpService)(_endPoint)
    Dim serv As IEmpService
    Dim result As Object = Nothing
    Dim mostRecentExp As Exception = Nothing
    Dim noOfRetries As Integer = My.Settings.NoOfRetries
    Dim initialDelay As Integer = My.Settings.InitialDelayInMS

    serv = channel.CreateChannel()

    For i As Integer = 0 To noOfRetries

        Try
            result = functionToCall.Invoke(serv)
            mostRecentExp = Nothing
            Exit For
        Catch cte As ChannelTerminatedException
            mostRecentExp = cte

            Thread.Sleep(initialDelay * (i))
        Catch enf As EndpointNotFoundException
            mostRecentExp = enf
            Thread.Sleep(initialDelay * (i))
        Catch stb As ServerTooBusyException
            mostRecentExp = stb
            Thread.Sleep(initialDelay * (i))

        Catch vf As FaultException(Of ValidationFault)
            'no retry

        Catch exp As Exception 'any other exception 
            mostRecentExp = exp
            Thread.Sleep(initialDelay * (i))

        Finally
            If channel.State = CommunicationState.Faulted Then
                channel.Abort()
            Else
                channel.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    Next
    If mostRecentExp IsNot Nothing Then
        Throw New ServiceExceptions(String.Format("Call to method {0} failed", functionToCall.ToString()), mostRecentExp.InnerException)
    End If
    Return result
End Function
```

I determine whether a retry is required or not depending on the type of exception I get, which all are fine.
the issue I'm facing is `result = functionToCall.Invoke(serv)` where the result is an object and it can contain a custom error object, and in that case it wont be an exception.
to get to the error I can do something similar to: 
    `If TypeOf result Is SaveAddressResponse Then
        ElseIf TypeOf result Is SaveDetailResponse Then
        End If`
which looks messy so like to know If I could use delegate to get errors from the `return` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should consider making all of these responses implement a common interface, e.g. `IFailureReporter` which allows you to get at any errors in a uniform way. Then you *only* need to cast to that interface (which you can do unconditionally if *all* of your responses implement that interface), and check for the error that way.

EDIT: If this isn't feasible, there's one other *possible* way, storing a per-type delegate in a dictionary. It's not really clear what you want to *do* with the error, or how it's represented in each of your response objects... but something like this would do it, *if* you know the exact types of the response objects (not just types they're compatible with). This is C# code, but similar VB code should be feasible - just less likely for me to get right:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>
     ErrorExtracters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>
{
    { typeof(SaveAddressResponse), response => ((SaveAddressResponse) response).Error,
    { typeof(OtherResponse), response => ((OtherResponse) response).ErrorMessage,
    ...
};
```

Then:

```
Func<object, string> extractor;
if (ErrorExtractors.TryGetValue(result.GetType(), out extractor))
{
    string error = extractor(result);
    if (error != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm restricted in changing the response object coming to the client.The usage of the above private function is: `Public Function SaveAddress(ByVal addInfo As AddressInfo, ByVal user As loggedInUser) As SaveAddressResponse Implements IEmpService.SaveAddress
        Return CType(ServiceCall(Function(x) x.SaveAddress(addInfo, user)), SaveAddressResponse)
    End Function` I was thinking maybe pass in another parameter to ServiceCall, but not exactly sure how to go about it.

Comment: @melspring: It's hard to give advice without the full information. It's *possible* that dynamic typing could help you here, performing overload resolution at execution time... but basically if you can't use the most natural solution, whatever you do is going to be messy. I have *one* idea, but it would be fairly brittle... will edit that into the answer.